# Weird font on all browsers on my Win10

Tags: windows-10, fonts

Recently I've noticed a weird font being applied across all the browsers (Chrome, Internet Explorer, MS Edge and Firefox) installed on my Windows 10 workstation.

[image: Web Page with Weird Font]]

This font is not applied to the body of the page, but to some headings.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a quick look at the site you screenshotted and it looks like they're using Helvetica Neue for their heading font and it's likely that this one is causing issues. The body font is Cambria which is why it isn't showing up as a problem in the body.

I can think of a couple of reasons for it showing up as a problem font.

The first is that the font is being substituted. Helvetica Neue is a commercial, licensed font that isn't included with Windows by default. It is possible that you only have one variant of it, in this case, the outline variant. Each browser is asking the os for that font and it's coming back with the only type it has. The likelihood of it being that increases if you installed something new recently that might have its own fonts.

To get around that your best bet might be to remove the font or disable it (and someone else might have a better answer than that). To uninstall it, click into Settings > Personalisation > Fonts. Search for the Helvetica Neue, click on it and click on the Uninstall button. The other option, in this case, might be to install the rest of the font. If the software package or whatever it was that installed the outline variant of the font has other fonts you can install it might be worth an explore in those folders and see if you can install one of the other Neue variants.

The second possibility is that the font file is corrupted or being crossed over somewhere. This is more likely if you have licensed the font at some point in the past and in this case, I would just reinstall it and restart (n.b. not shut down and power up again an actual restart).

A restart in the first instance before doing either of these might not be a bad idea in any event just in case there is a corrupted font cache or something else holding on to the font file and mucking up the browsers' rendering.

Comment: Thanks @Greig, that explains it and now it make complete sence to me. I have a strong feeling this works for me. However, I'll remove Helvetica font from the PC and let you know.

Comment: Removing Helvetica worked for me and now the page looks clean. Thanks!